# Запрос в триггере

Tags: oracle, plsql

Добрый день! Пришлось столкнуться с Oracle, но я начинающий разработчик и прошу строго не судить мой код.
При создании документа в таблице FORMS срабатывает следующий триггер :

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "REA"."AUTOCREATE_TRIGGER" 
BEFORE
INSERT ON REA.FORMS
FOR each ROW
 WHEN (NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=59 OR NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=60) BEGIN
  IF :NEW.LIST_OF_FORMS_ID=59
      THEN   AUTOCREATE.AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(:NEW.POWER_FACILITIES_VID, :NEW.ID);
END
```

Как видно, триггер вызывает процедуру, которая создает поддокументы и добаляет записи в таблицу PR340_FR73_S1_T1и все поддокументы имеют FORMS_ID который связан с ID в таблице FORMS

```
 PROCEDURE AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1(
    POWERFACILITIES NUMBER,
    FORMSID NUMBER) AS
    BEGIN
FOR ROW IN (SELECT VID FROM poe_steam_turbines 
            WHERE POWER_FACILITIES_VID = POWERFACILITIES
            AND IS_ACTUAL = 1) LOOP
INSERT INTO PR340_FR73_S1_T1 (
        HAS_PROLONGATION ----ПРОДЛЕНИЕ
       ,HAS_REMARKING ---ПЕРЕМАРКИРОВКА
       ,HAS_REPLACEMENT --ЗАМЕНА
       ,HAS_REMOVAL --ВЫВОД
       ,POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID
       ,FORMS_ID
       ) VALUES (
         0
        ,0
        ,0
        ,0
        ,ROW.VID
        ,FORMSID
    );
    END LOOP;
END AUTOCREATE_PR340_FR73_S1_T1;
```

И в момент инсёрта в таблицу PR340_FR73_S1_T1 срабатывает триггер

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "PR340_FR73_S1_T1_EVENT" BEFORE INSERT ON PR340_FR73_S1_T1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 period NUMBER;
 BEGIN
SELECT PERIOD_ID INTO period FROM FORMS WHERE Id = :NEW.FORMS_ID; -- в этом запросе происходит ошибка из за :NEW.FORMS_ID

  --period:=2016;

   IF :NEW.HAS_REMOVAL = 0
   THEN 
        FILL_EVENT.FILL_REMOVAL_ATR(:NEW.POE_STEAM_TURBINES_VID, period,
        :NEW.STOP_ID, :NEW.REMOVAL_LAST_YEAR);
   END IF;  
END;
```

Если переменную period захардкодить то все нормально, или если вместо :NEW.FORMS_ID подставить значение из другой существующей записи, то тоже норм, я думаю что все таки новая запись еще создана и я не могу получить из нее значения, так как все триггеры before, но как тогда мне получить это значение из новой записи таблицы FORMS, до добавления записи в БД, изменение триггера в AFTER только вызвало кучу ошибок. Спасибо за внимание...

Comment: Какая ошибка возникает

Comment: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ORA-04091: таблица REA.FORMS изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это\n ORA-06512: на  "REA.FILL_EVENT", line 18\n ORA-06512: на  "REA.SCI_TURBINE_PAR_EVENT", line 10\n ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'REA.PR340_FR75-S1_T1_EVENT'\n ORA-06512: на  "REA.AUTOCREATE", line 549\n ORA-06512: на  "REA.AUTOCREATE_TRIGGER", line 3\n ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'REA.AUTOCREATE_TRIGGER'\n ]

Comment: Правда я не понял почему у вас ошибка не возникает если вы хардкодите id-формы, она должна возникать всегда. К сожалению в Oracle вообще нельзя из триггеров `for each row` обращаться к таблице, на которую срабатывает триггер. Стандартное решение: создаете еще одну таблицу. в триггере `AFTER INSERT ON FORMS
FOR each ROW` пишите в эту таблицу два поля `:NEW.POWER_FACILITIES_VID, :NEW.ID`. Делаете еще один триггер на FORMS, но без `for each row` в нем читаете эту таблицу и вызываете вашу процедуру. Очищаете таблицу

Comment: но ведь триггер у меня срабатывает на PR340_FR75_S1_T1  а обращаюсь я к таблице FORMS, ведь именно из нее я хочу получить период, и у меня это получается если вместо :NEW.FORMS_ID я введу ID существующей другой записи, но мне нужна именно та запись, которую я только начал создавать и на создание которой сработал триггер

Comment: У вас триггер  PR340_FR75_S1_T1 срабатывает когда запись создает процедура, а процедура ее создает, когда ее вызывает триггер на FORMS. Т.е. в момент, когда вы обращаетесь в FORMS изменение этой таблицы еще не завершено (не все триггера `for each row` завершились). Решение в посте выше вам точно поможет

Comment: Вы пишете свой код или отлаживаете чужой? Если первое, лучше перепишите вашу логику из триггеров в процедуры, потому что в таком виде это не поддерживаемо от слова вообще (что, собственно, и демонстрирует ваш вопрос). Если второе - то вам не повезло, но постарайтесь уговорить коллег на рефакторинг.